# RewriteRule not passing parameters to the page

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have entries in .htaccess file like this.

```
RewriteBase /
DirectoryIndex home.php
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteRule ^(.*)/gas-agencies-near-(.*) locate-gas-agencies-near-by.php?district=$1&locality=$2
```

But when I make a request like this

Bagalkot/gas-agencies-near-Bilgi

The URL is matching but the it is passing district and locality parameters as "". Please help me in  where i am doing doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There is some issues in your rewriterule. When you use `(.*)` in rule that means it will match everything.

```
RewriteBase /
DirectoryIndex home.php
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/gas-agencies-near-([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)$ locate-gas-agencies-near-by.php?district=$1&locality=$2
```

Please check the regex I have added in rule, so it will match for only limited portion.

Comment: Do you have any other rule added below this rule? how you are accessing your URL values, which you are getting blank, please post the code?